# Why is this Actionlistener on the JMenuItem not executing?

Tags: java, swing, events

I have been working on a homework assignment and I have run into a rather strange issue, I am trying to get 2 JMenuItems to call methods when I click them but for some reason the attached actionListeners are not working.

I added a System.out.println to the actionListeners as I assumed it was the method calls that were acting funny but that code also does not execute.

I had a look through Stack Overflow for similar issues with the other action listeners and I think I am doing the listeners part correctly.

This is my first time modularising my code like this so I assume it has something to do with that?

Where might I have gone wrong?

**Full Code**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;


class Test100 extends JFrame implements ActionListener

{
    //Setup Globals
    public static JPanel panelInnerFrame = new JPanel();
    public static JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane();
    public static int internalFrameCounter;
    public static int xOffset = 15, yOffset = 15, offSetIncrease = 15;//Windows position offset
    public static JMenuBar menuTop = new JMenuBar();
    public static JMenu apps = new JMenu();
    public static JMenuItem fontApp, imageApp = new JMenuItem();

    public Test100()
    {

        panelMaker();   //Make our panel
        menuBuilder();  //Call menu builder to build our menu

    }

    public void panelMaker()
    {
        //Desktop Pane, this is like a virtual desktop within our pane
        desktop = new JDesktopPane();

        //Set Desktop Pane to act as our Content Pane
        setContentPane ( desktop );

        //Set properties of our window
        setTitle ( "Test100" );
        setSize ( 1024, 768 );
        setVisible ( true );

        //Create a new JPanel,this will sit in the innerframe, we can add things here.
        panelInnerFrame = new JPanel();

    }

    //Method - menuBuilder - A method to build JMenus
    public void menuBuilder()
    {
        //Create a new menu bar
        JMenuBar menuTop = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar ( menuTop ); //We need to use the setJMenuBar with a JDesktopPane()

        //Add a JMenu
        JMenu apps = new JMenu( "Apps" );
        menuTop.add ( apps ); //Add Jmenu to the menu bar

        //Add JMenu Item
        JMenuItem fontApp = new JMenuItem( "Font App" );
        apps.add ( fontApp ); //Add Menu items to our JMenu

        //Add JMenu Item
        JMenuItem imageApp = new JMenuItem( "Image App" );
        apps.add ( imageApp ); //Add Menu items to our JMenu

        //Add listeners
        fontApp.addActionListener ( this );
        imageApp.addActionListener ( this );

    }

    //Method - frameFontMaker - A method used to build an internal frame displaying fonts
    public void frameFontMaker()
    {

            //Internal Frame, this is our floating box, it sits on our virtual desktop and takes multiple arguments
            JInternalFrame innerframe = new JInternalFrame
            (   "Font App", //frame name
                true,   //resizable
                true,   //closable
                true,   //maximizable
                true    //iconifiable
            );

            //Set properties of our innerframe
            innerframe.setSize ( 300, 300 );
            innerframe.setVisible ( true );
            innerframe.setLocation ( xOffset, yOffset );

            //Add a JPanel to our innerframe
            innerframe.add ( panelInnerFrame );

            //Add the innerframe to the desktop
            desktop.add ( innerframe );


    }

    //Method - frameImageMaker - A method used to build an internal frame displaying images
    public void frameImageMaker()
    {

        //Internal Frame, this is our floating box, it sits on our virtual desktop and takes multiple arguments
        JInternalFrame innerframe = new JInternalFrame
        (   "Image App", //frame name
            true,   //resizable
            true,   //closable
            true,   //maximizable
            true    //iconifiable
        );

        //Set properties of our innerframe
        innerframe.setSize ( 300, 300 );
        innerframe.setVisible ( true );
        innerframe.setLocation ( xOffset, yOffset );

        //Add a JPanel to our innerframe
        innerframe.add ( panelInnerFrame );

        //Add the innerframe to the desktop
        desktop.add ( innerframe );


    }

    public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent e )
    {
        //If fontApp menu item selected
        if ( e.getSource() == fontApp )
        {
            frameFontMaker();
          //System.out.println ( "Test" );
        }

        //If imageApp menu item selected
        if ( e.getSource() == imageApp )
        {
            frameImageMaker();
          //System.out.println ( "Test" );
        }
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )

    {
        new Test100();
    }//End Main


}//End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're shadowing the JMenuItem variables, so that your class has 2 extra JMenuItem objects more than it needs. Two you add to the menu, two, the class fields you don't. Within actionPerformed, you check for equality with the class fields.

```
class Test100 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    //...     

    public static JMenuItem fontApp, imageApp = new JMenuItem();  // fields -- never added to GUI

    //.... 


    //Method - menuBuilder - A method to build JMenus
    public void menuBuilder()
    {
        // ....

        //  *** re-declaring the variables here!! *** these are different variables and hold 
        // different objects
        JMenuItem fontApp = new JMenuItem( "Font App" );
        apps.add ( fontApp ); //Add Menu items to our JMenu

        //Add JMenu Item
        JMenuItem imageApp = new JMenuItem( "Image App" );
        apps.add ( imageApp ); //Add Menu items to our JMenu

        // ......

    }
```

Solution: don't shadow (or re-declare) the variables.

Change this:

```
JMenuItem fontApp = new JMenuItem( "Font App" );
// ...
JMenuItem imageApp = new JMenuItem( "Image App" );
//...
```

to this:

```
fontApp = new JMenuItem( "Font App" );
//...
imageApp = new JMenuItem( "Image App" );
//...
```

Note the difference?

Comment: This is why I come to Stack Overflow even if I do get downvoted often for being a noob :O That worked perfectly!

Comment: @Ninja2k: I'm glad it worked, but more importantly, do you now understand why your original code did not work? You need to understand the concepts to avoid doing this again.

Comment: yes, I was essentially creating two objects one global and one local and then referencing the local blank one.